# Smart sum in Rails based on Eager Loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails has a sum function that goes directly to SQL like this:

```
User.find(1).books.sum(:pages_count)
SELECT SUM("books"."pages_count") AS sum_id FROM "books" WHERE "books"."user_id" = 1
=> 3024
```

But if you are in a controller you might want to do eager loading like this :

```
users = User.limit(10).includes(:books)
users.first.books.map(&:pages_count).sum
=> 4325
```

This way you only do two SQL queries and the rest is ruby code.

I'm trying to do a method that can detect if the relation has been eager loaded and select the right sum function but with no such luck.

Here is my code:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Calculations
    def smart_sum(column = :value)
    puts self.loaded?
      if loaded?
        collect {|x| x[column] }.sum
      else
        sum(column)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Strangely the loaded? bit does not work in the method and so the SQL sum is always returned.
Any help?